# Multiconditional if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, random, numbers

How can I write code so that in a game where a 3 digit number is randomly generated (first 2 digits can be 0) I check if the number contains a 9. However, the number cant be 963 or 369. The number is currently generated in a way where each digit is independently generated. Each digit is a different variable so as to make checking win conditions easier.

My current code is below for reference. I know why it does not work but I don't have a solution.

```py
TABLE = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
for pp in range (100000):
    rand1 = random.randint(0,9)
    rand2 = random.randint(0,9)
    rand3 = random.randint(0,9)
    
    word1 = TABLE[rand1]
    word2 = TABLE[rand2]
    word3 = TABLE[rand3]
    
    print(word1, word2, word3)

    if (word1 == 9 and word2 != 6 and word3 != 3 and word2 != 9 and word3 != 9) or word2 == 9 and word1 != 9 and word3 != 9 or (word3 == 9 and word1 != 3 and word1 != 7 and word2 != 8 and word2 != 6 and word2 != 9 and word1 != 9):
        a +=1
print(a)
```

Comment: You are being way too verbose. Why not simply `n = random.randint(0,999)` and then check if n is in `[963,369]`? For *display* purposes, you could always display something like `37` as `037` (check out the string method `zfill`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
number = (word1, word2, word3)
if 9 in number and number != (3, 6, 9) and number != (9, 6, 3):
    ...
```

?

That aside,

- The indirection through `TABLE` looks completely useless.
- Why are you initialising a bunch of unused variables?

Comment: yea sorry about that. It was undeleted code from a previous version of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that uses a `while` loop to keep looping until a number that's not in `[963, 369]` gets generated, like this:

```
from random import randint

def get_number():
    while True:
        number = randint(100, 999)
        if number not in [963, 369]:
            return number
```

Now, you can call the function whenever you need a number:

```
for _ in range(10):
    number = get_number()
    print(number)
```

Output:

```
815
522
855
153
726
859
339
410
332
309
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the numbers to a string, then check if that string contains a 9.

```py
a = 0

for pp in range(100000):
    rand1 = random.randint(0, 9)
    rand2 = random.randint(0, 9)
    rand3 = random.randint(0, 9)

    numstr = str(word1) + str(word2) + str(word3)
    print(numstr)

    if "9" in numstr and numstr not in ["963", "369"]:
        a += 1
print(a)
```

But, instead of generating three random numbers, you could do the same with one !

```py
a = 0

for pp in range(100000):
    rand = random.randint(0, 999)
    print(rand)
    if "9" in str(rand) and rand not in [963, 369]:
        a += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating the 3 numbers independently doesn't make the process simpler and your TABLE list isn't bringing any benefit.  This also opens up the possibility of generating 000 which isn't supposed to be allowed according to your problem statement.  Presence of the 000 will skew the probability distribution of other numbers making it 1/1000 instead of 1/999.

You can obtain the result in a sum applied on a generator that produces Tru/False values indicating eligibility of randomly generated numbers:

```
a = sum( "9" in str(n) and n not in (963,369)
         for _ in range(100000) for n in [random.randint(1,999)] )
```